# React big calendar error setup

Tags: reactjs

I'm using  this line of code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import BigCalendar from 'react-big-calendar';
import moment from 'moment';

// Setup the localizer by providing the moment (or globalize) Object
// to the correct localizer.
BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment); // or globalizeLocalizer



export default class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
    }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
         <BigCalendar
            events={[]}
        />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But i'm getting this error console

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `timeslots` was not specified in `Calendar`. Check the render method of `Uncontrolled(Calendar)`.

And i'm getting no style on calendar...
What i have missed ?

Thanks in advance.
Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 0):

I need to define timeslots

```
<BigCalendar
timeslots={4}
events={[]}/>
```

and include style

```
import BigCalendarCSS from 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';
```